# Qual è il significato di "Miscia" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Non teneva più garzoni, da sei mesi aveva dato licenza all'ultimo, il britanno dagli occhi bianchi e i capelli di stoppa che sulla porta della casipola la sera urlava: «*Miscia*, dannata, vieni mangiare».

Ho cercato il significato del vocabolo "miscia", ma non l'ho trovato in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Sapreste dirmi cosa vuol dire in questo brano?

Comment: È possibile che sia un nome proprio? Somiglia a quello che spesso viene traslitterato “Misha” (o più correttamente “Miša”), che in russo è il diminutivo di “Michail”. Ma qui, semmai, è un nome femminile, visto l'aggettivo “dannata”.

Comment: Poi: è veramente “vieni mangiare”? Manca una “a” o quel personaggio parla in modo sgrammaticato?

Comment: Hai ragione, @DaG! Può essere il diminutivo di "Artemisia", appunto! E sì, sembra che questo personaggio parli così, in modo sgrammaticato.

Comment: @DaG: Vuoi scriverlo come risposta? Adesso la domanda mi sembra piuttosto stupida e ho pensato di cancellarla, ma forse si può lasciare, nel caso che qualcuno avesse lo stesso dubbio leggendo il libro.

Comment: Se vuoi, rispondi tu stessa, che hai anche tutti gli elementi sul contesto.

Comment: @DaG: Va bene, cerco di farlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Come ha detto @DaG, si tratta di un nome proprio. Dall'aggettivo "dannata" si può vedere che è un nome femminile. Il personaggio del brano è un garzone che lavora nella casupola dove abita la famiglia Gentileschi (il pittore Orazio Gentileschi con i suoi figli). Quindi, si può capire che "Miscia" è il diminutivo che usa questo garzone per chiamare Artemisia.

Answer (score 2):

Se britanno sta per anglofono, la citazione è chiara come il sole, al punto che posso dirti che non è fedele (sono madrelingua inglese)... Ovviamente sta per Artemisia, Misia (l'anglofono rifugge i nomi di troppe sillabe), solo che in realtà non direbbe affatto Miscia (il russo non c'entra per niente), direbbe Misgia (fondendo s e gi come la j francese, se hai presente "je suis".

Comment: La tua risposta contiene degli elementi utili. Pensi di essere in grado di scriverla in modo da non avere un atteggiamento paternalistico (“Fìdati”, “Continua così”...)?

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! Sono d'accordo con @DaG: penso che il tuo post possa  migliorare togliendo questi elementi. La ragione è che la risposta dovrebbe essere utile per altri utenti (altri lettori del romanzo) e quindi non dovrebbe essere redatta pensando solo a me. Cioè, a mio parere, queste cose vanno bene come commento, ma non dovrebbero essere presenti nelle risposte.

Comment: Ho tolto l'ultima parte del post: se vuoi, puoi scriverla come commento.